# Retraining Tensorflow for new class labels

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am building a classifier that predicts the damage of a vehicle(like high, low, medium, good). I referred to this GitHub repository

https://github.com/raviranjan0309/Car-Damage-Detector

There is a retrained_label.txt file in models/tf_files which consist of four classes 
not,
car,
high,
low

I do not want these four classes and I want my tf to predict one of the following
Good,
High Damage,
Low Damage,
Medium Damage

Is this possible ? 
Should I need to retrain the tf for these classes ?
If so how ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The file you mentioned only has 4 words in it and to be honest it is difficult to understand why they are in that file.

Normally, for any tensorflow related analysis, you have to retrain the algorithm to be able to predict based on new labels.

If you are new to ML/DL and Tensorflow, I would suggest looking into excellent tutorials on Titanic predictors where you can use a simple database to predict either one of two outcomes: survive or die

You can then use a similar code and just use a different dataset (in this case I guess a car dataset) to have it predict one of four possible outcomes for damage. The only problem is getting that dataset of course
(many examples, but here's one: https://towardsdatascience.com/predicting-the-survival-of-titanic-passengers-30870ccc7e8)

Without having at least a 1000 or so data point with car information where that damage is already listed, it would be quite challenging.

So just to summarize:
1) yes you have to retrain and probably need a different dataset too
2) you may be able to create a dataset with damage info based on what you already have
3) once training/testing sets are ready, you can then retrain using simple ML techniques

Comment: Yes, I am new to Tensorflow although have good working knowledge of ML concepts. I do not know which dataset are they using in here, but the system is predicting the damage severity quite decently(of course into four classes not, car,high and low). I wanted it to predict one of the four classes I mentioned above. So I tried just changing the text file contents to what I want but that didn't work. So I wanted to ask whether how to retrain it.

Comment: do you have a raw dataset for any of it? you can only train it based on the actual data set - it's currently trained to predict only those 4 labels, it won't work with anything else

Comment: No I do not have any dataset, But I don't really understand how the algorithm was trained there and on what dataset was it trained

Comment: my assumption is that the person who posted this, just didn't provide the data because it was either  a) copyrighted or illegal in some way or b) he just used this repo for his own purposes and has a dataset saved somewhere else,  but decided to share the final product with everyone else so you could maybe contact him directly. Also the file he provided that's important is in *.pb format and you could read about them here: https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/tool_developers/

Comment: *.pb file will contain only the graph information right ? If there is any copyright issues or anything with the data, then I guess I should not get the output right ? But the output seems fine . That's what my doubt is

Comment: I think if this person wanted to provide the original data, he would have already